# SMTP Gmail Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, smtp-auth

I have a problem with smtp gmail using codeigniter 3, I created this code in the controller folder with the file name Auth.php. so when the user clicks the register button a verification email will be sent to the email that was registered by the user

```
`   private function _sendEmail()
    { 
        $config = [
            'protocol' => 'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
            'smtp_users' => '***',
            'smtp_pass' => '***',
            'smtp_port' =>  465,
            'mailtype' => 'html',
            'charset' => 'utf-8',

        ];

        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
        $this->load->library('email',$config); 
        $this->email->initialize($config);

        $this->email->from('Email Sender', 'Full name in email');
        $this->email->to('Recieved email');
        $this->email->subject('Testing');
        $this->email->message('coba coba');

        if($this->email->send()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            echo $this->email->print_debugger();
            die;
        }
    }`
```

Comment: Did you forget to finish your post? You can [edit] it. See also [ask]. If you have a problem, you need to tell us specifically what that problem is, explain what investigation and attempts to fix it you've made so far, and ensure you provide a [mre] of the issue including relevant code, any error messages, relevant log entries etc which might help to diagnose the issue. At the moment, all we know is you have an unspecified "problem" - clearly that is not going to be something we can meaningfully help you with. Thanks.

Comment: I think smtp host is `smtp.gmail.com`